# Expressing 2D Gabor transform as 1D spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum

The Gabor transform (Short-Time Fourier Transform with Gaussian window) is represented as $U(t,\omega)$, where $t$ is the time, and $\omega$ is the frequency.  The author of a monograph ([Seismic Inverse Q filtering](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING), pg. 190) is asking for the Gabor spectrum to be transformed from 2D to 1D in the following fashion.

1. Define $\chi = \omega t$
2. Take the 2D amplitude spectrum $|U(t,\omega)|$ into a 1D amplitude spectrum as $|U(\chi)|$

The issue that I am struggling with is that $\chi$ is the product of $\omega$ and $t$.

The following Matlab code demonstrates that $\chi$ does not continue to increase monotonically.  Note the "sawtooth" appearance of $\chi$.

So how do I take the 2D signal as a 1D signal?  For each $\chi$, there should be exactly one $|U(\chi)|$.

```
N0 = 51;
N1 = 1604;
fs = 1.0e3;
f = (fs/2) * linspace(0,1,N0);
omega = 2 * pi .* f;
dt = 1 / fs;
T = (N1-1) * dt;
t = linspace(0,T,N1);

chi = [];
cnt = 1;
for i = 1:length(omega)
   for j = 1:length(t)
        chi(cnt) = omega(i) * t(j);
        cnt = cnt + 1;
   end 
end

figure;
plot(chi);
xlabel('\chi')
ylabel('Value')
```

[image: Chi image]

However, the Gabor spectrum is a 2D matrix, similar to this example, where $\omega$ is on one axis, and $t$ is on the other axis:

[image: Gabor transform]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 11.1 shows the equation for $A$:
$$A(\tau,\omega) = A_0 \exp\left(-\frac{\omega \tau}{2Q}\right)$$

We see that $A$ really only depends on the product of $\tau$ and $\omega$, therefore by defining a new variable $\chi = \omega \tau$ we can rewrite this expression as

$$A(\chi) = A_0 \exp\left(-\frac{\chi}{2Q}\right)$$

Perhaps this helps.